# limit photon geocoding results to a specific place

Tags: r, geocoding

I would like to geolocate addresses from a particular city.

I have just recently used [photon R package](https://github.com/rCarto/photon) as a geolocation solution with certain degree of success. Unfortunately, some results are placed very far away from the place I am trying to geolocate, even if I use location bias:

```
df = geocode(address, limit = 1,key = "highway", locbias = c(-0.8787, 41.6486))
```

As far as I know Photon can accept keys and values, but don't know how to use it, further than what I did (If I am not wrong it will search only OSM's objects tagged as `highway=*`). Is there a way to tell phonon to search only OSM's objects tagged as `highway=*` AND are located within a city (maybe using OSM's `is_in=*`)?

Reproducible code:

```
# Only the last address is located in Zaragoza (OK). The others are not (KO)
address = c("Pablo Neruda, Grancasa, Zaragoza", "GAVIN, 14, La Magdalena, Zaragoza", "La Magdalena, Zaragoza", "calle Ciprés, 8, Alfonso, Zaragoza", "calle asalto, 52, La Magdalena, Zaragoza") 

df = geocode(address, limit = 1,key = "highway", locbias = c(-0.8787, 41.6486))
```

Note: from what I see, some wrong results are due to the fact that are not proper streets but neighbourhood names, hence my `key = highway` is messing things up. Still, some others are streets that do exist in Zaragoza, although with some minor spelling differences -hence that's why Mexico scored better).

Comment: do you understand why the returned location is far away? Is there an address with a matching name there, or is it just wrong? Can you give us at least one example?

Comment: Yes, there is a street named like that in another country, hence the need to limit results to a city.

Comment: let me prepare some reproducible data and I will add it to the question.

Comment: @Spacedman, I have added an example, thanks for pointing this out.